# MPLAB X IDE : Can we get "console like" output using dsPic?

Tags: pic, microchip, mplabx

I was wondering, can we get console like output using command like **"printf"** on MPLAB X IDE ???

Console Output just like standard C ??

example : if i want to get the value/data of the variable on output screen. How to display it ??

If not, What can be alternate options to get the debug output ???

I am using **dsPic33E** on **MPLAB X IDE v3.00**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The printf family of functions does not print to a debug console. It prints to the applications default display which, for the embedded PIC, is the first UART peripheral. If you want to see this in some form of debugging console, you'll need a ftdi like cable that gives you a ttl serial port and plug it into the output of the UART.

Comment: You also need to #include <stdio.h>